# Laravel : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to delete an object model `Studio` which `hasMany` model `Member` and `hasMany` model `Game` and set a behavior to it's `hasMany` models after deleting it, the idea is to change the `Member` and `Game` models `studio_id` attribute to a default `Studio` object, in other words to change their attached `Studio` to another one when the `Studio` which they `belongTo` get's deleted.

Here's the code to attempt so

```
$studio = Studio::find(Input::get('id'));
$games = $studio->games;
$members = $studio->members;
$merged_collection = $games->merge($members);

$merged_collection->each(function($item){
   global $studio;
   $item->studio()->detach($studio);
   $defStudio = Studio::find('5');
   $item->studio()->associate($defStudio);
   $item->save();
});

$studio->delete();
```

Both Game & Member model's have the method

```
public function studio(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Studio');
}
```

All columns are named correctly , I'm able to retrieve all games associated with a studio , same thing with games, and the opposite way around, however when I try to execute the code after doing verification and else I get the error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach()
```

I thought that perhaps the items I'm attempting to use the method `detach()` are not object instances, but as I understood whenever I use the `$collection->each(function($object){})` as denoted, I'm retrieving the object instances within the collection.

I'd appreciate any kind of guidance or help. 
Thank you.

Comment: `detach()` is `BelongsToMany` method. What you need is `dissociate()` http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.html#method_dissociate

Comment: Thank you @deczo ! Was not mentioned on the book I'm reading on Laravel ,  however I get the same error just with dissociate() as the undefined method

Comment: Maybe you are using older version of the framework. This method is pretty new. You can use alternatively `$item->studio_id = null;`

Comment: @deczo that did solved it. It's quite strange as the version I'm using is about a month old , thank you.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk What method would that be for `hasMany()`? I get the same undefined method error for both `detach()` and `dissociate()`

Comment: @Pathros there's no such method, call `dissociate` on the counterpart of the relation, or simply set `$related->FOREIGN_KEY = null` and save